# Sprite Editor no corta correctamente mi atlas Unity 2D

Tags: unity, unity2d, 2d

soy nuevo utilizando el motor de Unity 5. Tengo el problema de que al momento de hacer slice a mi sprite atlas este corta mal, ya lo habia hecho antes y si lo hizo correctamente, pero quise agregar unos sprites más y al momento de cortarlo salió asi, hasta ahora no puedo solucionarlo, muchas gracias.

[image: De seguro es algo sencillo pero es que aún no domino muy bien las configuraciones]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui una version anterior que si recorto correctamente

Comment: Así como aparece, toca el botón Slice. Creo que con eso debería bastar. Si selecciona cosas que no debería es posible que hayan quedado píxeles casi transparentes en la imagen.

Comment: cuando selecciono en slice es donde pasa lo que ves en la imagen, en el editor de imagenes esta todo correcto transparente, ya lo habia hecho antes y lo corto correctamente pero quise agregar unas imagenes más y al momento de querer cortarlo denuevo aparece así.

Comment: Bueno, siempre lo puedes cortar manualmente. Si tienes Photoshop o algún programa con la herramienta de varita mágica podrás detectar irregularidades fácilmente. Insisto, es posible que haya píxeles que aunque no son visibles están ahí y no permiten que el recorte automático funcione bien.

Comment: sigo sin encontrar respuesta, hacerlo manualmente no podría ser porque necesito que sea exacto las colisiones, adjunto uno anterior que si corto correctamente de mi anterior proyecto, intento cortarlo y se bugea denuevo, es muy raro

Comment: lo verifique con programas como photoshop y corel draw que son los que utilizo para hacer los diseños y no, todo es transparente